# jQuery help with jumpy slidedown menu

Tags: jquery, menu, slidedown

I have this code written in jQuery to have a simple on hover slide down menu.  It works, however it is sometimes very jumpy.  When you slide your mouse over it at a certain spot or a bit fast, it will jump open/close and flicker...not sure how to remedy that?

Here is my current code:

```
this.navLi = jQuery('nav ul li').children('ul').css("display","block").hide().end();
this.navLi.hover(function() {
    // mouseover
    jQuery(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
}, function() {
    // mouseout
    jQuery(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you try out the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin. It works quite well for things like this.

Here's an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pBhtW/). It fits quite well into how you've set up your code.

And just a note, your first selector is looking for a tag `<nav>` is that correct?

**Example**
*HTML*

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="head">
            First
            <ul>
                <li>1.1</li>
                <li>1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="head">
            Second
            <ul>
                <li>2.1</li>
                <li>2.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
jQuery(function() {
    this.navLi = jQuery('#nav ul li').children('ul').css("display","block").hide().end();
    this.navLi.hoverIntent(function() {
        // mouseover
        jQuery(this).find('> ul').slideDown(100);
    }, function() {
        // mouseout
        jQuery(this).find('> ul').slideUp(100);
    });
});
```

*CSS*

```
#nav, #nav ul { list-style: none; }
#nav, #nav * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
li.head { width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px black solid; }
```

Comment: @Drackir-thx for that, although I am trying to do it without adding more load with a plugin but this will have to do for now...

Comment: @Rick: The plugin is very small ( <1.5kb ). You can add it into your jquery or common javascript file (if you have those) and then it's only a small addition that doesn't require loading an extra file. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the effect of the **second** `true` (parameter) in the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method, from the documentation:

> **.stop( [ clearQueue ], [ jumpToEnd ] )**
>   **clearQueueA** Boolean indicating whether
>   to remove queued animation as well.
>   Defaults to false.  **jumpToEndA**
>   Boolean indicating whether to complete
>   the current animation immediately.
>   Defaults to false.

Just remove the second parameter and see if this is what you want.

Comment: are you saying to change both stop() on mouseover and mouseout to stop(true,false)??  Or just mouseout?

Comment: @Rick: change it to `stop(true)`, now I would change it on both but it's really up to you you may also remove the first parameter too and just use `stop()`! test it and use what suits you best!

Comment: @ifaour-thx for the help but i tried all combinations and it gets worse because with it set to false, if i mouse over it fast, on the next hover, it won't even open all the way...